# How to access nested json object inside array in react js

Tags: javascript, json

I want to access nested JSON object values by iterating. This is the data I get from my query:

```
{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb89200","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b7b"],"name":["Camaro Coiled Tubing"]}]}
{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb8920d","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b82"],"name":["DANCO Coiled Tubing"]}]}
{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb8921b","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b7d"],"name":["San Joaquin Bit"]}]}
```

I would like to create a second array with only the firm and name and have tried the following:

```
      vendorList.forEach(function (d) {
        vendorArray.push({
          id: d.firms._id,
          name: d.firms.name,
        });
      });
```

My output looks like this:

```
Vendor List:  [{}, {}, {}, {}]
```

An empty array.

Comment: Your code shouldn't run at all, since your input data is not an Array (as far as you've shown)

Comment: `"_id"` is not a direct child of `"firms"`, `"firms"` is an array in this case. If you are certain that there will always be one item in array, `[0]` could be used to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is actually an array of objects you can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the values embedded in the nested objects/arrays.

```js
const data = [{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb89200","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b7b"],"name":["Camaro Coiled Tubing"]}]},
{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb8920d","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b82"],"name":["DANCO Coiled Tubing"]}]},
{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb8921b","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b7d"],"name":["San Joaquin Bit"]}]}];

// For each object in the array map over the firm data
// and, for each firm, extract the data from each firm array
// and return only those two values in an object
const out = data.flatMap(obj => {
  return obj.firms.map(firm => {
    const { _id: [_id], name: [name] } = firm;
    return { _id, name };
  });
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your vendorList array is wrong.

```
let vendorList = [{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb89200","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b7b"],"name":["Camaro Coiled Tubing"]}]},
{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb8920d","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b82"],"name":["DANCO Coiled Tubing"]}]},
{"_id":"654d4224fb04863b8eb8921b","firms":[{"_id":["65423d5c240388c1594e7b7d"],"name":["San Joaquin Bit"]}]}]
```

then did the traversal same as your code,but id & name are at first index of firms so made the changes as per it.

```
let vendorArray = [];
vendorList.forEach((vendor) => {
    vendorArray.push({
        id: vendor.firms[0]._id,
        name: vendor.firms[0].name,
    })
})
```

**Final output:**

```
[
  {
    id: [ '65423d5c240388c1594e7b7b' ],
    name: [ 'Camaro Coiled Tubing' ]
  },
  {
    id: [ '65423d5c240388c1594e7b82' ],
    name: [ 'DANCO Coiled Tubing' ]
  },
  { id: [ '65423d5c240388c1594e7b7d' ], name: [ 'San Joaquin Bit' ] }
]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. The original object was the result of an Mongodb aggregation function. Thanks.

Comment: Can you upvote & accept it, if it helped resolved your query.

Answer (score 0):

> To access nested JSON objects within an array in ReactJS (or
> JavaScript in general), and based on your specific case, you need to
> adjust how you're iterating over the data. Specifically, you'll need
> to take into account that firms is an array of objects within each
> item of your vendorList. Also, it looks like both the _id and name
> properties within each firm are arrays themselves, which is somewhat
> unusual. Assuming you want to access the first _id and name for each
> firm,

```
let vendorArray = [];

vendorList.forEach(function (d) {
  // Iterate over each firm within the firms array of the current item
  d.firms.forEach(function (firm) {
    // Assuming _id and name are arrays and you want the first element of each,
    // use firm._id[0] and firm.name[0].
    vendorArray.push({
      id: firm._id[0], // Access the first element of the _id array
      name: firm.name[0], // Access the first element of the name array
    });
  });
});

console.log(vendorArray);
```